# Can you extend an Orchard module?

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I want to do a tweak on the Search module, but I obviously don't want to mess with the original source, so is there a way to 'extend' an existing module?  If so how?  Or must I create a new module, copy the code from the Search module, and tweak that?

Comment: If you want to override the Search Service for example you can re-implement the service and suppress the one built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case you need to create your own module. Whether to copy the code and tweak it or create your own implementation of some existing interface from scratch is up to you - this relies on your specific scenario and the extent of the tweaking needed.

There are a few ways to extend existing things in Orchard:

- Any service interface that implements `IDependency` can be overridden by simply putting your own implementation in your module
- `OrchardSuppressDependency` attribute can be used on your class to explicitly disable certain existing implementations
- Shape templates and normal views can be overridden in the theme as descibed in [docs](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Accessing-and-rendering-shapes)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  (sorry, I'm very new to Orchard ... I'm sure that's a rookie mistake)

Comment: Glad you found it helpful and welcome to the community! Orchard may seem complicated at first but after you understand its general architecture things will suddenly look more clear.